# Some confusedness of BitmapFactory.Options.inBitmap

Tags: android, bitmap

As everyone knows, If BitmapFactory.Options.inBitmap  option is set, decode methods that take the Options object will attempt to reuse an existing bitmap when loading content.My problems are:

1. how it works
2. if I reuse an using bitmap，what will the reused bitmap happen
3. If this situation will happen：Two images simultaneously on the screen，one reuse another one，then two bitmap the images used will repeat。
4. how to use inBitmap Correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you supply a `Bitmap` object as an `inBitmap` you should make sure that you don't use the supplied `Bitmap` in any other place anymore, as its content will most likely be replaced with new data (new pixels).
Second, you must make sure the supplied `Bitmap` has the same resolution and type of pixels as the result of the desired operation.

So when should you use the `inBitmap` parameter? Whenever you can reuse a `Bitmap` that is similar to the one you want to create. Why should you use it? Because it is way more efficient than not doing so. If you supply a reusable `Bitmap`, the space it occupies in memory will be used for the new one; the system will not have to allocate new space in memory (usually a bitmap requires a lot of memory space) and the Garbage Collector will not have to recycle it.

When you should not use the parameter? When you are still using the old `Bitmap`or when the resolution or pixel type doesn't match the new one.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: thanks.But how I can know if the old Bitmap is still using or not using

Comment: Although this is not complete solutions to my problems,but I accept it as my answer